# Nodejs - Send data with ajax to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I try send the values to my server, but If I try, my console show me the error:

```
Cannot POST /
```

I try see other examples, and I try with this codes:

**My** `index.html`:

```
function sendData() {
  var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();
  var context = latestResponse.context;
  var mail = context.email; // I can see the data of these variables perfectly on the console


 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/",
  crossDomain:true, 
  dataType: "json",
  data:JSON.stringify({email: mail})
 }).done(function ( data ) {
      alert("ajax callback response:"+JSON.stringify(data));
   })
}
```

**My** `server.js`:

```
'use strict';

var server = require('./app');
var port = process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;

server.on('request', request);

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server on port: %d', port);
});

function request(request, response) {
    var store = '';

    request.on('data', function(data) 
    {
        store += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function() 
    {  console.log(store);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.end(store)
    });
 }
```

**My repository:**

```
FolderRepository
    public
     - js folder
     - img folder
     - css folder
     - index.ejs
    server.js
    app.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your server is running on the other port. This is your port

`var port = process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;`

and in ajax request you need to post to the url `http://localhost: + your port`

And also every time when you receive a request, your request will attach a new event handler to the `data` event, so after 10 attached events you will get an warning message about the leaking of the memory.

This code works. The main difference is that I call `http.createServer()` and you get it from the `app.js`. Look into the `app.js` and see if the server is created appropriatly.

Try to see if your server is created correctly.

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 3000;

var proxy = http.createServer();

proxy.listen(port);

proxy.on('request', request);

function request(request, response) {
    var store = '';

    request.on('data', function (data) {
        store += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function () {
        console.log(store);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.end(store)
    });
}
```

Comment: In the case  I try with localhost:3000/server, and dont work. My port is 3000

Comment: remove the server part from the localhost. You don't call to the `js` file, but to the route `/`

Comment: I will edit with new code. Same error: `Cannot POST /`

Comment: I want send this values to server because I'll use this, is it the best Practice
?

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi see your app.js, the problem is there.

Comment: Hi Suren! In the case I see the problem, with your say to me. The problem is I dont have any route to wait something, I'll create other router and trying again, Thanks very much! +1 and mark

Comment: you would benefit from the use of a server side framework like express. It's not mandatory obviously but almost everyone uses a framework on top of node.js for a reason.

Comment: @Kevin also I suggest you to see SailsJS

Comment: I see your sails.js and raise you koa.js. Jokes aside I'm aware of the frameworks  available I'll just say I have a personal preference for the micro web framework approach vs the all in one rails/django/sails.js approach.